# hiredis C API : reply for HMSET vs HSET

Tags: c, error-handling, hash, redis, hiredis

When I execute `HMSET` the reply contains string "OK" in success case.
However with `HSET`, `reply->str` is null.
Is there any particular reason for this difference?

In case of error, both seems to give error string in reply.

I wanted to confirm what are the checks to be done to ensure command was successfully executed.
Is below correct?

- HMSET:

  - reply should not be null.
  - reply->str should be 'OK'.
- HSET:

  - reply should not be null.
  - reply->str should be null.

Output:

```
# gcc redis.c -lhiredis
# ./a.out
Connected to redis localhost
Correct commands:
[HMSET] Reply: OK
[HSET] Reply: (null)

Wrong commands:
[HMSET] Reply: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command
[HSET] Reply: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command
#
```

Code:

```
# cat redis.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    redisContext *c;
    redisReply *reply;
    const char *hostname = "localhost";
    struct timeval timeout = { 1, 500000 };

    c = redisConnectWithTimeout(hostname, 6379, timeout);
    if (c == NULL || c->err) {
        if (c) {
            printf("Connection error: %s\n", c->errstr);
            redisFree(c);
        } else {
            printf("Connection error: can't allocate redis context\n");
        }
        return;
    }
    printf("Connected to redis %s\n", hostname);

    /* Correct commands */
    printf("Correct commands:\n");
    reply = redisCommand(c,"HMSET testKey name value");
    printf("[HMSET] Reply: %s\n", reply->str);
    freeReplyObject(reply);

    reply = redisCommand(c,"HSET testKey name value");
    printf("[HSET] Reply: %s\n", reply->str);
    freeReplyObject(reply);

    /* Wrong commands */
    printf("\nWrong commands:\n");
    reply = redisCommand(c,"HMSET testKey name");
    printf("[HMSET] Reply: %s\n", reply->str);
    freeReplyObject(reply);

    reply = redisCommand(c,"HSET testKey name");
    printf("[HSET] Reply: %s\n", reply->str);
    freeReplyObject(reply);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [HSET](https://redis.io/commands/HSET) says that it returns the *integer* number of fields that were added.  If you are modifying a field rather than adding a field, it will return 0.  You should not be looking at it as a string.

The documentation for [HMSET](https://redis.io/commands/HMSET) says that it returns "OK" or an error message